# Delete file if it's not in an array

Tags: php

I have a bunch of extra garbage uploads in a directory from when I was testing my app. The files I want to keep are in a table in my database. I want to delete a file in the directory if it's not in the table. Here is my attempt

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT file_name FROM DummyFile';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();
$files_in_use = $statement->fetchAll();

$statement->closeCursor();

$path = getcwd();
$all_files_in_directory = scandir($path);

$all_files_in_directory = array_diff($all_files_in_directory, array('.', '..'));



foreach($all_files_in_directory as $file) {
    if (!in_array($file, $files_in_use)) {
        unlink($file);
    } 
}



?>
```

However this code deletes every single file in the directory regardless. Which means my conditional in the loop is evaluating to true every time when it shouldn't be. Please help

Comment: $files_in_use what this will have

Comment: What do you see if you `echo` `$file` and `$files_in_use`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assuming `$files_in_use` is an array of filenames. It's not; it's an array of database rows, each being an array itself.

To get just the filenames you need:

```
$files_in_use = array_column($statement->fetchAll(), 'file_name');
```

The rest of your code should then work.

Comment: And the first parameter for array_column is suppose to be an array not a string

Comment: Nevermind this works just make sure you do array_column($statement->fetchAll(), 'file_name')